# Translate Multi Lingue Header Top and Header Main

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

How can I translate the header-main and the header-top of a page? Link: novosite.iqnus.com.br

Maybe there is some hook to add in the functions.php file.

Thanks.

Comment: try `_e()`, `__()` functions

Answer (score 0):

0) Read the translation docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

1) Make sure the strings you want to translate are recognized in your Themes' gettext files - recompile and translate them accordingly and make sure the correct language files are available in the languages directory of your Theme

2) Every dynamic content can be translated by using Plugins like WPML or qTranslate

Answer (score 0):

Try This plugin it's useful for Translate Multi language Header Top and Header Main

https://wordpress.org/plugins/gtranslate/screenshots/

You can put short code header.php where you show.